# Origin header missing from cross origin request to S3 on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, request, cors, access-control

I am trying to load an asset (a font) from an s3 bucket. Fonts on Firefox and IE need to have Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers returned in the response. Unfortunately it seems that Chrome is not sending an "Origin" request header. Since it is not sending an Origin request header, S3's CORS policy is not returning the required Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Here is an example request screenshotted from the Chrome inspector panel:

**Why is there no "Origin" Header in the Requset Headers?!**

[image]

The page making this font request is at https://proximate.com and is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before making the `GET` request for the font, Chrome would have sent a preflight `OPTIONS` request for the font resource. It is in this preflight request that Chrome would have sent the `Origin` header.  S3's CORS policy would have returned the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response to this preflight `OPTIONS` request.
Thereafter, Chrome would have made the GET request for the font -- the request that you have shown in the screenshot. Chrome would not send the `Origin` header in this `GET` request now. And as the screenshot shows, the request was successful (Status Code 200 OK). Also note the Amazon headers (starting with `x-amz-`) and `Server: AmazonS3` present in the response. 
It does seem that your site https://proximate.com would have received the font from Amazon S3. Was that not the case?

For more details please see the links https://spring.io/understanding/CORS and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same issue and after hours of banging my head against the wall I found that something with Chrome's HTTP caching mechanism prevents the `Origin` header from being sent. This is a Chrome-specific issue as I could not reproduce it with Safari. You can check whether this is the case for you as well by toggling the "Disable Cache" option under the [Network tab of Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucVP.png).

To force your request to ignore the cache, use appropriate `cache` option ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)). This is my final working code:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-store', // for some reason Chrome's caching doesn't send Origin
})
```